# Modelling Aggregate Roots with EF Core 3.X

Tags: domain-driven-design, aggregateroot, ef-core-3.0

Lets say I have these entities:

- Customer
- Order
- Product

All three are aggregate roots, because all three need to be loaded and modified independently of one another. Since aggregate roots cannot contain other aggregate roots, for the Order aggregate root, we need a couple of more entities: OrderCustomer and OrderProduct. These are read-only and children of the Order aggregate.
This way, since Order aggregate needs the customer and product, it loads OrderCustomer and OrderProduct entities, which are read-only. Order never loads Customer or Product.

This all makes sense however, the question I have is, how is this implemented in EF Core where you cannot map multiple models to same table? Do you define the OrderCustomer and OrderProduct as non-mapped models and load them by hand in your Order repository? I dont see any other way to do this.

(Please dont suggest using stored procedures or direct SQL or anything like that)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `OrderProduct` and `OrderCustomer` probably wouldn't be entities but rather value obejcts that have their data persisted along with the `Order`.  Fetching the data from the existing `Product` and `Customer` tables would not be necessary and, in some cases, quite detrimental to your data integrity.

Since one aggregate should not contain a reference to another aggregate the idea is, as you appear to have it, to reference the related aggregate by id.  However, if you need more information than just the id you can, again along the lines that you seem to be thinking, create a value object that contains the id along with some pertinent bits.  I like to have the value objects that are specific to the aggregate as nested classes to make it apparent where they belong but that is a design choice.

As far as "duplicating* the data of the related aggregate in the `Order` to re-constitute the value object consider a `Product` that represents a pair of "red socks".  If you only store the id and then later fetch the description using the product id the description may , in the meantime, have changed to "blue socks".  That will result in some issues with your client.  Denormalizing the product description into the `Order` (via an `OrderLine` or `Order.Line`) would not cause any confusion in that regard and keep the discrepancy internal to the company without affecting the customer since a pair of "red socks" had been ordered.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Just so I am understanding this correctly, OrderProduct and OrderCustomer would be additional tables, which would contain Ids to Product or Customer and have some additional attributes from those tables. These values would be the values that were on Product/Customer at the time when Order was created, so there is no worry about duplication of data. As far as data integrity, this could go both ways. For example, if customer, who has orders, called and said he moved, the order which were already created would be shipped to his old address.

Comment: `OrderProduct` and `OrderCustomer`, if modeled as value objects, would not be additional tables in this case but in other cases for a *one-to-many* relationship you may need to add a table.  The additional customer details would be stored with the `Order` and the additional product details on the `OrderItem`.  Even for a shipping address an order would contain the address for historical reasons.  If a customer has a new shipping address then it would not be correct for all previous orders to now refer to the new address.

Answer (score 0):

When using EF Core and if OrderCustomer and OrderProduct are entities that belong to your Order Aggregate root, you can load them by hand in the repository just like you said. There's nothing wrong with that approach. Actually Microsoft's own architecture guide does just this. Here's the code from the example:

```
public async Task<Order> GetAsync(int orderId)
    {
        var order = await _context.Orders.FindAsync(orderId);
        if (order != null)
        {
            await _context.Entry(order)
                .Collection(i => i.OrderItems).LoadAsync();
            await _context.Entry(order)
                .Reference(i => i.OrderStatus).LoadAsync();
            await _context.Entry(order)
                .Reference(i => i.Address).LoadAsync();
        }

        return order;
    }
```